# CSS3 RotateY Tile Flip doesn't work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transforms

I've created a CSS3 tile flip effect with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container">
<div class="flipper">
<div class="front img1">
</div>
<div class="back" id="back1"></div> // img1 and back1 are specified in the CSS with the background-image property.
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-toggle.flip .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    border: 0;
}
```

However, as can be seen [here](http://leonkempers.com/peter/index2.php), the effect doens't work properly. On Chrome, Firefox and Safari, it properly displays the back image of each tile, but Internet Explorer simply mirrors the front image.

How can I solve this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Have a read at http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip#ieflip

In the end, to support IE10+, you need to apply the rotation to the two sides and not their container.. ([*because `preserve-3d` is not supported*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#the_ms_transform_style_property))